# Why am I getting an error message when trying to "cat" my char device driver?

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, chardev

I've written a simple character device driver for Linux.

It is a simple message storing/retrieving system where the messages are stored in kernel space.

I should be able to do something like this:

```
echo "message 1" > /dev/mydevice
```

and then retrieve the message with

```
cat /dev/mydevice
```

The messages are stored in a queue.

When I try to retrieve a message that I hard coded in for testing (the message is "hello"), I get the following command line output:

```
cat /dev/mydevice
hellocat: /dev/mydevice: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

So I get the hello message as intended, but clearly I'm doing something not quite right.

Here is the function that handles device reads.

```
static ssize_t device_read(struct file *filp, char *buffer,
               size_t length, loff_t * offset) {
  unsigned long result;
  int message_size;
  struct message_list* message = pop_message(&global_message_list);

  if (!message) return -EAGAIN;

  message_size = message -> message_length;

  result = copy_to_user(buffer, message -> message, message_size);

  printk(KERN_ALERT "res: %lu, msg_size: %d, len: %d\n", result, message_size, length);
  if (result == 0) return message_size;
  else return message_size - result;
}
```

Comment: I think `cat` keeps trying to read until it hits EOF (`read` returns 0). In this case, once you’re out of messages, you go immediately to `EAGAIN`. Try hard-coding an empty message after `"hello"` in the queue and see if that works? (If this is the actual problem, that’s probably not the best solution, but it’s easier to test; for one thing, it would be hard to make it return exactly one message to each reader in a thread-safe manner that way.)

Comment: Returning EAGAIN when there are no more messages is part of the requirement for my assignment. I'm a little confused as to how I can overcome this given that I need to return 0 for EOF.

Comment: @DanielH also, does that imply cat will call my read function multiple times? I thought reads traditionally returned the number of bytes read.

Comment: If you hard-code the queue to be `"hello"` then `""`, then the first read will get `hello`, the second will get an empty string with length 0 meaning EOF, and the third will get EAGAIN.

Comment: Yes, `read` returns the number of bytes read. But that might not be the whole file, for two reasons: 1. Obviously if the buffer passed in to `read` is less than the number of bytes available to read, then you don’t have the whole thing and need to call `read` again to get the rest. 2. Maybe the file you’re `read`ing from is a pipe, TTY, or other device where not all the data is available at once; in that case a `read` will return whatever data’s available and the next will block until there’s more.

Comment: Okay that makes a lot more sense. great explanation. Also, adding an empty message worked. I was able to read the "hello" correctly. Hopefully I've got it from here, thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cat` utility calls `read` more than once for each file, until it reaches EOF (which is [signified by `read` returning 0](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)).

This is because not all data may be available right away. If the file is bigger than `cat`s internal buffer, it will of course need to call `read` multiple times to get the full data. Even if the number of bytes returned by `read` is less that the length of the buffer, it will need to call `read` again in case more data is available later (as could be the case if the input is a TTY or pipe). Therefore, you need to return 0 in order to get `cat` to think it’s at the end of the file and stop reading.

(For more detail on how `cat` works, you can check [the source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/cat.c;h=a3680a3fc6a5ebf3a72ba914281ff98e805291d4;hb=HEAD#l151), and the [`safe_read` function](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gnulib.git;a=blob;f=lib/safe-read.c;h=896c115e9f8519a8a22664a5b37740389f9c505c;hb=HEAD).)

A simple way to handle this would be to put a zero-length message in your queue after each “real” message, so that the next `read` will return EOF. However, this won’t work correctly if you have multiple readers at the same time; in that case, one reader might read a message, then the other reads the EOF, then the first reads another message, so that one reader gets two messages and the other gets zero. It’s up to you and/or your instructor whether to make your device threadsafe.¹

This also indicates another potential problem with your code, which you only partially handle: if you have a message bigger than the buffer passed in to `read`, you discard the rest of the message instead of saving it for the next `read`. Again, this might be an acceptable shortoming, or not.

---

¹ I’m not sure if it’s possible to make it threadsafe; that depends on how well you can distinguish different readers, and I don’t know enough about kernel code or writing character devices to say if that’s possible.